# use output of azure function is azure data factory

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-data-factory

There is a possibility to use an Azure function immediatelly in Azure Data Factory and you can send parameters to the Azure function as inputs. But now I want to use the output of my Azure function immediatelly in my Azure Data Factory. Is this possible or do I need to save the result of my Azure function in a database/blob?
With the Azure function, I'm doing some manipulation on data and after that, I need to join the result of the Azure function with some data of another database. I would prefer to join both data sets directly in Azure Data Factory instead of in the Azure function for readability reasons

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking, but Data Factory pipelines do have the ability to call an Azure Function as a step in the pipeline, including passing parameters in the POST. As for computing results, and storing results, I'm not sure there's a single right answer to such a question. Please edit to clarify your question.

Comment: Well the question is, can I use the computing result of the Azure function directly in the next step of the ADF pipeline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure Data Factory pipelines can connect with Azure Functions, in any step of the pipeline.

Calling an Azure Function is via a POST. The pipeline may also capture data returned from the Azure Function (as the return of the call to the Function), and may then use that data in a follow-on pipeline step.

If your Azure Function is producing something substantive (e.g. generating a large CSV), you might want to consider storing your Function output somewhere (like a blob) and returning the URI of this output, in your Function return. You can then work with that data in a subsequent step in your pipeline.